# Group video calling between Mac OS X and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macos, video, conferencing

iChat can do group video chats well on OS X.  It looks like Skype can do group video chats on Windows 7 now (but that's not in the Mac version yet).

Is there something that will play nice with both platforms (along with good video quality)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Skype might be the answer.  They put out a [Mac beta](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/macosx/beta/) that has multi person video conferencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
http://www.tokbox.com/

that allow video conference online on both platforms.

Comment: We've looked at that.  The quality wasn't quite up to what we needed.